# It is possible to add Google Analitics cookies without scirpt?

Tags: cookies, web-applications, google-analytics

it's possible that somethink is setting google analitics _ga and _gid cookies without script in code in my app ?

I am starting work in old project Angular + .Net and this cookies are randomly set but I can't found any code to do this. I have not working with google analitics yet.

The only think that I found it was Content Security Policy allow to :

*"Content-Security-Policy": ...; script-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com ; ... ; connect-src 'self' https://api.someDomain.com wss://api.someDomain.com https://analytics.google.com ;...*

It's possible that this is a source of this cookies ? I know that others app under the same domain are using google analitics.

Comment: check the google analytics measurement protocol.

Comment: No, don't "check" the MP. That's an unrelated comment. Open your network tab and see if GTM or analytics.js are loaded.

That would be the likely source of your cookie.

Comment: @BNazaruk No, any of this js. files are not present.

Comment: Well then you should debug it. Clean cookies, set breakpoint on the very first line of JS and reload the page, see if the cookie is set now. If it is, it's set by your backend. If not, then you probably wanna debug it further, doing some debugging from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946617/determining-origin-of-cookie-which-javascript-or-tracking-pixel

Comment: I tried what you suggest. But it's important that I don't recognise the moment when the cookies are set. This don't occurs every refresh only one for a some unknow time period. And not i each browser. Usualy I see this cookies in Edge.